# Creating an Abstract Background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to create an abstract pink background similar to this one:

[image]

I can't seem to find any tutorial on how to do it. How are those wavy looking lines created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are actually created using blends in **Adobe Illustrator**.

[image: blend]

Comment: Thank you for the comment Scott. I wasn't aware it could be done in Illustrator. Very helpful!

Comment: @JamesJeffery Glad to help. The lines are really a 10 second thing in Illustrator. Then simply copy/paste to Photoshop. Much, much, much easier than using brushes or any Photoshop-only method.

Comment: Best answer because this was very useful and helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Download Photoshop brush for the waves go to this [link](http://www.starwalt.com/photoshop_stuff4.html) and 
download [Linear Blend Brushes](http://www.starwalt.com/photoshop_stuff4.html) and install the brush.

Using the linear blend brush you can create the wave and for the rest you can do it by wrap or download this [brush](http://www.brushking.eu/388/revnart-smoke.html)

Hope it helps you!!!